# Need to customize the linker in CodeBlocks

Tags: arduino, codeblocks

I am using [CodeBlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code%3a%3aBlocks) to compile Arduino projects. The default linker command is the following:

```
$avr-gcc  -o bin/Release/test2.elf .objs/cores/CDC.o .objs/cores/HardwareSerial.o .objs/cores/HID.o .objs/cores/IPAddress.o .objs/cores/main.o .objs/cores/new.o .objs/cores/Print.o .objs/cores/Stream.o .objs/cores/Tone.o .objs/cores/USBCore.o .objs/cores/WInterrupts.o .objs/cores/wiring.o .objs/cores/wiring_analog.o .objs/cores/wiring_digital.o .objs/cores/wiring_pulse.o .objs/cores/wiring_shift.o .objs/cores/WMath.o .objs/cores/WString.o .objs/libraries/libraries.o .objs/test2.o   -Wl,--gc-sections -Os -mmcu=attiny84  -lc -lm
```

The Arduino IDE uses a different approach. It uses [avr-ar](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/man/man1/avr-ar.1.html) to create a single library and then performs a link on it:

```
/usr/bin/avr-ar rcs build-attiny84at1/libcore.a  build-attiny84at1/WInterrupts.o  build-attiny84at1/wiring_analog.o  build-attiny84at1/wiring.o  build-attiny84at1/wiring_digital.o  build-attiny84at1/wiring_pulse.o  build-attiny84at1/wiring_shift.o  build-attiny84at1/CDC.o  build-attiny84at1/HardwareSerial.o  build-attiny84at1/HID.o  build-attiny84at1/IPAddress.o  build-attiny84at1/main.o  build-attiny84at1/new.o  build-attiny84at1/Print.o  build-attiny84at1/Stream.o  build-attiny84at1/Tone.o  build-attiny84at1/USBCore.o  build-attiny84at1/WMath.o  build-attiny84at1/WString.o
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny84 -Wl,--gc-sections -Os   -o build-attiny84at1/test.elf build-attiny84at1/sketch.o build-attiny84at1/test.o build-attiny84at1/libcore.a  -lc -lm
```

My problem is the CodeBlocks link statement results in code that is substantially larger. The only difference I can see between the two is that the Arduino way creates a single library first. When I compared the disassembly (.lss file) of the two, the Arduino one had a nice tight file with the source code interspersed. In contrast, the CodeBlocks one had a lot of mystery code, and there were none of my source code statements.

Is there a way to get CodeBlocks to create a library via avr-ar first, and then link with that? That seems to be my problem, or am I missing something?